# Example of an invertible ideal which contains a zero divisor as one of its generators

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $R$ be a ring and let $I$ be an (integral) invertible ideal of $R$. Let $J = \{a_1,\ldots,a_r\}$ be a minimal ideal generating set of $I$ in the sense that any proper subset of $J$ will not generate $I$.

> I was wondering if it was possible that one of the $a_i$ was a zero divisor of $R$.

Clearly, any invertible ideal does indeed contain at least one regular element and hence any principal invertible ideal won't provide such an example.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: How do you define invertible ideals inside a ring that is not a domain? I know them as $R$-submodules of the quotient field $K$ of $R$, but that makes no sense. Do you simply replace $K$ by the total ring of fractions?

Comment: @JeskoHüttenhain Yes, I think this is the common definition as used in Eisenbud.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is quite possible.
 Let $k$ be  a field,   $R=k\times k$ and $I=R$.
Then  $a_1=(1,0), a_2=(0,1)$ form a minimal set of generators for $I=R=\langle a_1, a_2\rangle$ but both $a_1,a_2$ are zero divisors of $R$.

**Nota Bene**
Contrary to what you claim this minimal set of generators  contains no  regular element.

Comment: What if I change the minimality condition imposed on the ideal generating set to "there is no other ideal generating set with strictly less generators"? Then your counter example doesn't work anymore since $(1,1)$ is a generator of your ideal.

Comment: take the ideal generated only by $a_1$ it is still invertible and the generator is a zero divisor